# How do I fix a failed build error [E0635]: unknown feature 'proc_macro_span_shrink'?

Tags: substrate-node-template, error, build

Following the instructions at (https://bruno.id/preparation-for-the-substrate-workshop/) until I received a build error, executing the instructions under the 'Error' heading, I received the following error E0635.[image]

I executed: `rustc --explain E0635` which provided the following output:
[image]

My ubuntu and rust toochain versions are as follows:[image]

[image]

How might I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rustup default nightly-2022-07-24 && rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

IMO, it's always good to follow the latest Polkadot release CI's Rust toolchain.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.30

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue today and `rustup update` doesn't work.
And I came to an idea.

```bash
rm -fr target Cargo.lock
cargo check
```

that's it.
But anyone know what's the cause of it?

Answer (score 7):

For those who are having the same problem since `version 1.72.0`, you need to do the same: pause updates of nightly rust.
You can do this by editing `rust-toolchain.toml` file:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2023-06-15"
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue, `rustup default stable` solved it

Answer (score 3):

The tracking issue on the rust github is this: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/113152

In short, removing `Cargo.lock` and recompiling should fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your nightly. You are using one from 2020, that is quite old. Running `rustup update` should do it.

Comment: I updated, thanks! I'm still getting some build errors, but they are new errors. Progress! =)